Have dnsmasq resolve multiple domains form local hostnames
I am running dnsmasq 2.90 inside a Debian 11.0 based docker container as part of Pi-hole 5.18.2.
I would like to configure dnsmasq to serve the addresses of my local hostsnames for multiple local domains (both .local and .subdomain.mydomain.com) as a local application has the .local domain hard coded. I can only make it work for one domain at a time.
This container is providing DNS and DHCP services for my local networks. As part of the Pi-hole set-up addn-hosts=/etc/pihole/local.list is added to the .conf file mounted at /etc/dnsmasq.d. This list contains a list of ~30 IP addresses from local and locally accessible subnets and and hostnames, such as:
192.168.1.10 server01
192.168.2.20 server02
100.115.x.x server03

dnsmasq is serving the local search domain over DHCP both as specified in domain=subdomain.mydomain.com and dhcp-option=option:domain-search.subdomain.mydomain.com in separate config files mounted at /etc/dnsmasq.d, as well as set as a local domain with local=/subdomain.mydomain.com/.
This search domain, as well as the IP of the DNS server, is accepted and implemented as expected by my clients:
❯ cat /etc/resolv.conf
…
search subdomain.mydomain.com
nameserver 192.168.2.2

A nslookup of a hostname in the addn-hosts works as expected, adding the search suffix and returning the correct result:
❯ nslookup
> server01
Server:     192.168.2.2
Address:    192.168.2.2#53

Name:   server01.subdomain.mydomain.com
Address: 192.168.1.10

I would like to return the same IP for server01.local:
> server01.local
Server:     192.168.2.2
Address:    192.168.2.2#53

** server can't find server01.local: NXDOMAIN

I have tried adding local to the .config files as local=/subdomain.mydomain.com/local/ both with and without domain=/subdomain.mydomain.com/local/ and separate domain=subdomain.mydomain.com domain=local entries. This either does not change the behaviour, or (if I add the two domain= entries) the nslookup then works for .local and not for .subdomain.mydomain.com.
How can I have dnsmasq respond with the hostname IP for both .local and .subdomain.mydomain.com domains?

then you have to add search subdomain.mydomain.com local in the search of resolv.conf

Thank you @admstg. I've added local to resolv.conf by specifying it as an option in the docker compose file as per docs which was adopted.
A client nslookup for e.g. server01.local still produces NXDOMAIN.

For anyone that finds this in the future, the answer (as is often the case) is that I was being stupid.
.local is reserved for mDNS and so, by telling my dnsmasq device to try and resolve .local and announce it's ability to resolve .local I was breaking mDNS. I was also testing the resolution using nslookup, which does not resolve mDNS queries.
By removing all of the references to .local in dnsmasq, restarting the services and refreshing the DHCP leases and testing .local resolution through a ping, it is working.
